# Create Clone applications in android

Tags: android

I have created a project in android.
But now i need to create the same project for multiple vendors, Only color scheme and Web Services will change.

I am trying to do make copy of the apps and change the package name of the application. But in any case if there is change in 1 app then i need to work on other apps too. So please let me know is there any way so that i can create a single source code and May able to change the UI in the existing app so every app have the same update .

Need to change :

1. Color scheme.
2. Logo.
3. Name of the app.
4. Web Apis.
5. Google Map Key and the push notification certificates.

But source code will be same for all

Regards
Amit

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: Thanks @TimKranen i have never used this  , need to check , Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBuild/article.html#building_gradle_variants) you can find a nice tutorial about flavours. I think that's exactly what you need.

The steps for building flavours in Android are:

Use the productFlavors closure of you app/build.gradle file to define different variants of your product.

```
productFlavors {
    prod {
        applicationId = "com.vogella.android.gradlebuildflavors.prod"
        versionName = "1.0-paid"
    }

    mock {
        applicationId = "com.vogella.android.gradlebuildflavors.mock"
        versionName = "1.0-free"
    }
}
```

After defining these flavors you can select them in the Build Variants view in Android Studio.

[image]

**Providing different resources for the flavors**

In order to define a different behavior for a certain flavor, you need to create suitable folders for the defined flavors under app/src/.

Flavor specific resources override the main resources. For example, if you provide a different application icon in a flavor the Android build system picks up the flavor specific one.

**Providing different source sets for the product flavors**

The directories in the src/ folder are called source sets. Every product flavor can define its own source set.

Code files are not replaced as resources, they are combined. For example, you cannot have a com.example.MainActivity activity in your app/main/java/ folder and a different implementation in another flavor. If you try this, you receive an error message about duplicate class definitions.

You can still provide different implementations by avoiding the creation of the class in your main source folder and instead create a class in each flavor.

Example of different src's:

[image]